# Where do I make a feature request to drupal.org?

Tags: community-official-site

What is the best place to make a feature request about the drupal.org website?

I probably spent an hour searching.  There is/was the redesign project, there is the drupal.org issue queue but I was refused access.

FYI - I'd simply like to suggest that project owners have a tab for "roadmap" or "project Future".  Sure, the summary page can include that but often it is crammed with things and maintainers forget to talk about what plans they have, what they need, etc.

Comment: this question appears to be off-topic - please see the help section of this site, including the 'What Topics can I ask about' - in the 'and it is not about' you will find 'Issues about drupal.org, or any of its sub-domains'

Comment: Thats odd.  I was told that is what the community tag is for.  If not you should probably delete it.  http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/q/3238/12432.

Comment: I humbly disagree as I think it is appropriate.  Also the reference has a footnote qualifying it:Bugs found on modules, Drupal itself, or Drupal.org (and its sub-domains) should be reported in the appropriate issue queue on Drupal.org. 
Security issues should be reported following the process defined on How to report a security issue.

Comment: This question is not about a bug report. It is asking in which drupal.org queue ask a specific feature request. The OP shows to know some of the existing project queues used on drupal.org and asks what the better project queue is. I admit it, it's not quite easy, to understand this.

Answer (score 1):

*Generally speaking*, the correct place to post feature requests for Drupal.org is the [**Drupal.org customization project**](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupalorg) issue queue.

However, you also wrote:

> FYI - I'd simply like to suggest that project owners have a tab for "roadmap" or "project Future".

If you just want to *suggest* that project owners publish a "roadmap", you can add that suggestion to the [community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2190239). It is a wiki so you don't request anything - you just do it (like I just did).

If you want to actually modify the project page layout by having a feature where project owner's may add an addtional tab for "Roadmap" to the page summary, you request this in the [**Project**](https://www.drupal.org/project/project) module's issue queue

Finally, I shall *not* suggest you use the [Webmasters](https://www.drupal.org/project/webmasters) issue queue for any type of feature requests.  The Drupal.org webmasters issue queue is for reporting spam, broken links, or user account problems at Drupal.org - and that is about it.  My experience is that nothing much happens to feature requests posted there, even if the request just involves flipping a trivial setting in a module already installed. The webmasters obviously have the power to do this, but they do not make decisions about such things.  They usually move feature requests to the Drupal.org customization project, and bug reports to the [Infrastructure](http://drupal.org/project/infrastructure) project.

Answer (score 0):

There are indeed quite a few "projects" on Drupal.org that might be a candidate for suggesting such feature request. My best bet for you would be the "projects" [Project](https://www.drupal.org/project/project) or [Project Issue Tracking](https://www.drupal.org/project/project_issue).

However, are you sure you want to suggest such feature? Things like "roadmap" are typically located already in either of these areas on drupal.org (related to a specific module and/or distribution):

- in the module's issue queue (often using "roadmap" or "release" in the issue title or issue summary), such as for the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/forena?text=roadmap&status=All&priorities=All&categories=All&version=All&component=All) module.
- within the community documentation, which you should be able to find via the "Read documentation" link on the project pages.
- on the module's project pages, such as for the [ArrayShift](https://www.drupal.org/project/arrayshift) distribution.

The technique that I believe works best so far, is what I've started to use in (eg) the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module. I.e using issues such as [Charts 7.x-2.0 Release](https://www.drupal.org/node/2382151) and 
[Charts 7.x-3.x Release](https://www.drupal.org/node/2395779). These are "parent" issues to which other issues are referring to as their "parent" issue. Combined with the status (color) of each child issue you then also get an idea of the progress of such release. Checkout those parent issues to see that technique at work.

If such feature ever gets requested/implemented, I'd assume/expect it to be another field without the "Resources" section when you edit the project page of a module,  where today you can already enter links to Demos, Screenshots, Community docu, etc). These links, if provided, are then shown within the "Resources" block when viewing the project pages.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer this question basing on what I learned in the period I was site maintainer on drupal.org. My answer doesn't reflect in any way what the current site-maintainers think, or the thought of the maintainers of any module.

The first project queue one would think is the one for the [Project](https://www.drupal.org/project/project) module since Drupal.org is effectively using that module, but I think it's improbable the current maintainer would plan to add such feature, if that is not generic enough to be applied to other sites as well. The answer is probably going to be something on the lines of "If you want to implement that feature, you can implement it in a custom module."
Drupal.org does use [custom modules](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupalorg) to implement those features that are not currently used in any module, or to alter how some of the features are implemented in existing modules.

If the feature request involves writing code, then the project queue for Drupal.org customization project is the best choice. In this case, I would also provide a patch for such feature to be implemented.
If the feature request is about a module to enable, I would use the [Drupal.org site-maintainer](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/webmasters) project queue, since some of the site-maintainers have the permission to enable modules on Drupal.org.

In both the cases, be ready to convince other users this is really necessary. In the case of custom code, it is much preferable to be ready to provide a patch for one of the custom modules used on Drupal.org, if one of the maintainers find the feature request interesting.